# My sticky navbar works on jsfiddle but not offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just recently made this sticky navbar with a little bit of jquery and realised that it doesn't work . When i tried copying my code to jsfiddle everything worked fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header onmouseover="this.style.background='white'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#e6e6e6'">
<img src="Photos\logo.png" width="210px" height="150px">
</header>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">Model</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="main">lots of words......</div
</body>
</html>
```

And the scripts.js file :

```
var n=$(".navbar"),
    ns="navbar-scrolled",
    head=$('header').height();
    $(window).scroll(function()  {
            if( $(this).scrollTop() > head) {
                n.addClass(ns);
            }
            else {
                n.removeClass(ns);

            }
});
```

The css file is the same as in my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jsuc4kL5/54/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default JSFiddle runs your script on window load, which means it runs *after* the DOM has been loaded.  You need to do this yourself normally.  Just a slight change will fix it...

```
$(function() {
    var n=$(".navbar"),
    ns="navbar-scrolled",
    head=$('header').height();
    $(window).scroll(function()  {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > head) {
            n.addClass(ns);
        }
        else {
            n.removeClass(ns);
        }
    });
});
```

You just need to wrap your code like this...

```
$(function() {

    // your code goes here

});
```

There are other ways to do the same, but that will fix your problem.